# Scroll view with image in it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, storyboard

In my storyboard application.

I followed this tutorial for my `scrollview` with image:

http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/uiscrollview-examples/

For `scroll` to work I'm doing like this:

**You can do this by dragging over the `scrollView` and `imageView` as properties** and then setting the content size in `viewDidLoad` like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.image.size;
}
```

I think there is something wrong with `properties`.But, unable to figure out...

But my image is not scrolling.Please help.

Comment: self.YourScrollerView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 480);

Answer (score 1):

try this code...

```
[self.scrollView setContentSize:self.imageView.image.size];//also try with  CGSizeMake(320, 520)
[self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[self.scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:scrView];
```